# Load Image from pointer in CUDA with export of dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport, hbitmap

I am new to this kind of stuff. I'm trying to create a function which is equivalent to the histogram function of an image. I am using windows forms application to show the histogram (and load the image) and CUDA/c++ to make the histogram. I am mentioning from the beginning that I am NOT using openCV, glut, OpenGL or any other third library. Carrying on... I am trying to pass a bitmap to an unmanaged c++ DLL. The problem here is that I don't now how to reference that bitmap in the c++ code. (And even how to get the RGB out of it).
Snippets of code:

c# :

```
private void calculateHistogram(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
    unsafe {
        int** matrixAcumulated;

        var date = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

        matrixAcumulated=NativeMethods.GenerateHistogram(date.Scan0, pictureBox1.Width);

        bmp.UnlockBits(date);

        // Write the string to a file.
        System.Console.WriteLine(matrixAcumulated[0][0]);
    }
}
```

Dll import :

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace HistogramProcessingCs
{
    class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("HistogramProcessingCpp.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern unsafe int** GenerateHistogram(IntPtr bmp, int dimensionImage);
    }
}
```

c++ :

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)  int** __stdcall GenerateHistogram(unsigned char *bmp, int dimensionImage)
{
    //How to refere the bitmap from the bmp pointer?
    //dimensionImage is Width = Height
}
```

Comment: I'm digging into this

Comment: I hope my answer helps people out there :)! Thanks for that question too. Now I know how to do c++ stuff with c# :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I worked out something after 2 hours of googling, stackoverflowing and microsoft documentationing!

Because you're using CUDA I think you only want fast and nice solutions, that's why I tried to find a way with which you can modify data without copying it many times only because of C# and C++ connection.

That's what I've done so far.

Some things are important.
I used an integer pointer, that's a bit messy with the current code.
You can of course use instead a char pointer which makes much more sense (haven't tested this).
Another thing is the `System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat`.
It's really important to know which you have choosen. In my example I've choosen `PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb`.
The byte order is (so far I learned) just how the name is.

## Example:

*32bppRgb* stands for **red, green and blue** which consume each **8 bits**.
However because it's this format and not **24bppRgb** it consumes a whole integer(8 bits aren't used). In this case the first 8 bits arent used (left to right thinking) so to set a pixel to red it works like this. (Sorry formating didn't worked as expected...)

|  8   |  8  |   8   |   8  | consuming bits

|empty | red | green | blue | color

| 00   |  FF |   00  |  00  | color code for red

So the code for red is this
=> 0x00 FF 00 00
and as decimal it's 16711680. That's where the number in the C++ comes from.

## ***C++ Code:***

Header file "NativeLibrary.h":

```
namespace NativeLibrary
{
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall PassBitmap(int* number, int size);
}
```

Cpp file "NativeLibrary.cpp":

```
#include <NativeLibrary.h>

void NativeLibrary::PassBitmap(int* number, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        number[i] = 16711680;
    }
}
```

## ***C# Code:***

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("NativeLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void PassBitmap(IntPtr bmp, int size);

public System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = null;


public void GenerateAndModifyBitmap()
{
    //The pixel format is essential!
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(100, 100, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

    //Just which region we want to lock of the bitmap
    System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new System.Drawing.Point(), bmp.Size);

    //We want to read and write to the data, pixel format stays the same (anything else wouldn't make much sense)
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

    //This is a pointer to the data in memory. Can be manipulated directly!
    IntPtr ptr = data.Scan0;

    // This code is specific to a bitmap with 32 bits per pixels.
    // Ignore current calculations. They are still work in progress xD
    int size = bmp.Height;
    size *= Math.Abs(data.Stride);
    size /= 4;
    //Call native function with our pointer to the data and of course how many ints we have
    PassBitmap(ptr, size);
    //Work is finished. Give our data back to the manager
    bmp.UnlockBits(data);
    bitmap = bmp;
}
```

This code would generate a bitmap which is completely red.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You nailed it!!

Comment: Haha thanks a lot :D. If there's anything left according this question feel free to comment. I'm just thinking about improvments